# Hp4250 printer starts off fast then slows to a crawl

Tags: windows-7, printing, printer

We have a HP4250 network printer on a Windows 7 Pro computer, that each day prints the first two or three print jobs quickly.  Afterwards, it slows all printing to a crawl.  Have set the resolution to DRAFT, reinstalled printer drivers, all updates are current, paper guides are set correctly, checked pickup rollers, installed a brand new tray 2, checked the spool settings and even tried to print directly from a USB cable.  Nothing seems to resolve this issue.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: If you turn off the printer and after a minute turn it back on, is it still slow? If not, it could be a setting. If it is slow it's something internal (overheating?) where it needs to rest for hours before printing fast again.

Answer (score 0):

Update your printer driver or go to a different one (PCL5, PCL6, Postscript.)  According to HP, printing may be slow if you access Preferences or printer Properties, but an updated driver will take care of this.
http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&taskId=110&prodSeriesId=412144&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=412144&objectID=c02262744